# Jumping at previous code without goto command

Tags: java, android

I have a news app which needs a refresh button

My code is something like this

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
//something on UI
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
restartfromhere:
//most of the networking is done here
// this is the part that I want to re-run to get new updates
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
//updates the data from internet in the application UI
}
}
```

Now i have a new button refresh, that needs to re-run the whole code again.

Like this, on refresh click

```
public void refresh(){
goto restartfromhere: 
}
```

Java doesn't have goto command and I know that its bad programming practice. So, what is the alternative method I can use?

Comment: Why cannot you just start a new instance of that task?

Comment: I am not sure how I am supposed to do that. Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new GetContacs().execute();
```

You don't need any goto s. You just have to execute your AsyncTask.